# Sourcetree не видит изменения

Tags: git, phpstorm, source-tree

Работаю в связке PHPStorm + sourcetree
Приведу пример.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В шторме при коммите изменения выглядят нормально (как видно на скрине поменяна одна строка, slidesToScroll изменили на -2)

А вот sourcetree не видит этого изменения и полностью весь код подсвечивает красным, и далее такой же зеленым
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из за чего это происходит и как это решить?

Comment: Выбросить SourceTree. Я только в этом году натыкался на то, что SourceTree показывал очень странное дерево коммитов. Уже дошло до разборок в руководстве (выглядело как не то замерждили в релиз, а релиз уже выкачен, а QA не тестили это). Но оказалось, это просто так оно решило отображать. Консоль и куча других клиентов нарисовала все правильно. Но волосы у тимлида шевелились

Comment: @KoVadim ну это не самое лучшее решение на данный момент..

Comment: @KoVadim как это относится к решению вопроса? я не спрашивал вашего мнения о то чем стоит пользоваться, а чем нет.

Comment: прямо. Но Вы конечно вправе пользоваться тем, чем Вам хочется. Но надо помнить, что иногда могут быть такие вот непрятности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобная проблема может быть как минимум из-за двух причин:

1. Возможна проблема с кодировкой файлов. Похожая проблема обсуждалась в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462339/why-are-some-js-file-diffs-not-shown-inline-in-sourcetree) вопросе на английском SO. Решение описанной в вопросе ситуации - сохранять все файлы в кодировке UTF-8.
2. Возможно, что diff tool, который используется у вас в SourceTree не понимает синтаксис js или что-то другое ему не понравилось. В таком случае, SourceTree пытает смотреть на содержимое файла либо как на текстовый файл, либо, в худшем случае, как на бинарник - и не может сделать вывода, что в исходнике поменялось. Для решение этой проблемы можете заглянуть [сюда](https://gist.github.com/jvandyke/4355099). По ссылке на github лежит .gitconfig в котором прописываются настройки использования diff tool из PHPStorm. Если вы настроите подобное у себя, то SourceTree для текущего проекта сможет использовать diff tool из PHPStorm, к которому у вас нет вопросов.

Первый вариант, я думаю, не подходит к вашей проблеме, а вот второй вариант выглядит весьма подходящим.